# vim colorscheme showing incorrect colors

Tags: colors, vim

I just grabbed the "Ultimate Vim Distribution" (http://vim.spf13.com/) that came with a bunch of colorschemes.

For some reason, setting a colorscheme inside my .vimrc (e.g. "colorscheme corporation") results in completely different colors than the colorscheme actually defines. Moreover, *manually entering :colorscheme corporation once vim has loaded a file* results in the colors changing to the correct scheme.

Upon loading a file, ":colo" and "echo g:colors_name" both print "corporation", as they should. "t_Co" is set to 256 before the colorscheme is set (if that matters). I'm all out of ideas!!

Thank you!

Comment: That seems like a GUI only color scheme. Are you sure it sets any cterm colors in it?

Comment: @Ercan You're right. What does that mean? And what tipped you off? Here is the file: https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/colors/corporation.vim

Comment: Another issue that wouldn't happen if the op didn't use a distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a GUI only color scheme. There's not much you can do unless you want to write a terminal version.

When you see a color scheme not behaving as expected you can always try it in GVim with `:gui<cr>`.
If you look at the code it has styling only for GUI. Here's an example line from this scheme:

`hi FoldColumn gui=italic  guifg=#192224   guibg=#A1A6A8`

And here's a line from Molokai which is a color scheme both for the GUI and the terminal versions of Vim:

`hi FoldColumn      ctermfg=67  ctermbg=16`

As you can see the colors aren't RGB values. `cterm` stands for color term.

Answer (score 1):

When the colorscheme only defines colors for GVIM, the GUI version of Vim, you can, if you have a high-color terminal that supports 88 or 256 colors, use the [CSApprox plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) to convert (once or automatically during Vim startup) the color definitions for the terminal.

Comment: I do have the CSApprox plugin, but it seems to load the wrong color scheme upon the first file load. Once viewing a file, I can type ":colo <colorscheme>" to see the proper colors. Why does it fail the first time?

Comment: It should work when you set the colorscheme in your `.vimrc`, because that is sourced first. Your "Vim distribution" may alter the usual sequence; I don't recommend using them.