# Vim doesn't show colors that macvim does

Tags: vim, macvim, color-scheme

I have tried two schemes, desert and wombat and I have set the colorscheme in my .vimrc file.  When I open vim from my shell I don't see the color of the scheme, but when I open with MacVim I do. In both, when I type :colorscheme I see the scheme that is set in the .vimrc file, but I fail to see why I don't see the colors.

As a note, I installed the [spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) distro and uninstalled it using the script provided.

Any thoughts of how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are the colors you see in macvim and terminal vim differents or you do not see any color in terminal vim ?

Comment: When using vim I don't see the theme background, I see the font colors though...

Answer (score 1):

First, check how many colors are supported by your terminal:

```
:echo $TERM
:set t_Co?
```

The colorscheme must actually support terminals by providing `term=` and `cterm=` definitions; many don't. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949536/813602 for how to work around this with the CSApprox plugin.

Inspect the colorscheme file (found in the `colors/` subdirectory), or use the `:highlight` command to list the current color definitions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Terminal emulators are limited to 256 colors max and often need manual setup to go beyond 8 or 16.
2. The coolest Vim colorschemes are designed for GVim/MacVim which can display thousands of colors.
3. Because of 1 and 2 it is impossible to fully emulate a GUI colorscheme in a terminal emulator if the GUI colorscheme uses colors outside the 256 colors in the X11 palette.
4. However, you could:

   - use a colorscheme that works in GUI *and* CLI
   - use a colorscheme that works *only* in CLI and another that works *only* in GUI and switch between them in your `~/.vimrc` depending on the context
   - use a plugin that converts your GUI colorscheme on the fly: [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2682), [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390), [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1809) or [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2924)
   - edit your colorscheme manually to add terminal support

Answer (score 0):

Terminals support 88 or 256 colors. Even if your terminal supports 256 colors, you have to specify that your terminal support it in your vimrc. (cf. [Using GUI color settings in a terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal))

```
set t_Co=256
```

Concerning your background, you should maybe specify that you are using a dark or a light background if your theme doesn't already declare it.

```
set background=dark
set background=light
```